# Switching between Python dictionaries and SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, dictionary

I have written python code which involves the use of dictionaries. I now wish to store my processed data onto a local SQLite database, but can't think of how to translate something like:

```
myDict[wordA] = [list of tuples (length changes per word)]
```

into SQL. I have changed `myDict` to be an SQL table with `word` being the first element, but I don't know how to assign columns to a variable list.

Do I have to change the structure of the DB?

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: You need to design yourself a table that your going to insert your data into

Comment: if the list of tuples (as opposed to a list of ints) makes it more difficult, that could be easily changed.

Comment: the ideal table i'd like is of the form:
    word TEXT, list INTS
but lists aren't an accepted dataform in sql.

Comment: Correct, which means you have to normalize your data

Comment: If your goal is simply a persistent key/value store, you can consider NoSQL options such as MongoDB, which have a more straightforward dict-like interface.

Comment: Do you really need SQLite ? Otherwise you can just serialize your dict using the standard pickle module: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Comment: @muckabout  and zepatou: you're both right -- I didn't really need SQLite. I looked into MongoDB and it's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you follow through a database tutorial like: http://www.quackit.com/database/tutorial/.

You'll want to make two tables, one that contains the word values, and one that contains the tuples. The tuples should not be in a list, but all have a separate row. 
You can link the tuples to the words using foreign keys. You can link multiple rows to the same word, in that way keeping the tuples from the list linked to a single word.

It would look like this, the foreign_key of the tuple table linking to the primary_key of the Word table:

```
Word table                              tuple table

primary_key   word                      primary_key     tuple     foreign_key
1             example1                  1               (1,2)     1
2             example2                  2               (3,9)     1
                                        3               (4,1)     2
                                        4               (4,2)     2
```

This would correspond to

```
myDict = {'example1' = [(1,2), (3,9)], 'example2' = [(4,1), (4,2)]}
```

Comment: One tuple can appear in the list of two different words. Would that be allowed in this scenario?

Comment: it wouldn't be fully normalized, but you could have another entry 1 (1,2) 2 so the tuple (1,2) would be in example1 and example2. Better(?) would be to make it a many to many relationship, but it depends on your usage if it is absolutely necessary.